# OutOfMemoryError at AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer

Tags: java, android, string, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20282148 byte allocation with 13784880 free bytes and 13MB until OOM
       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
```

I am trying to create PDF and using [this](http://github.com/Turbo87/apwlibrary) library:  It is giving this error at this [line](https://github.com/Turbo87/apwlibrary/blob/master/apwlibrary/src/main/java/crl/android/pdfwriter/PDFDocument.java#L76) (It is basically `StringBuilder#toString()`

PDF to be generated is very very huge.

I have tried many other solutions present on this website but they all are about analysis or breaking loop.

Is there any solution?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried adding this in your manifest file 'android:hardwareAccelerated="false"' , 'android:largeHeap="true"' within the application tags? Give it a try and let me know how it behaves.

Comment: @nupadhyaya I am trying to create PDF and using this library: https://github.com/Turbo87/apwlibrary

It is giving this error at: https://github.com/Turbo87/apwlibrary/blob/master/apwlibrary/src/main/java/crl/android/pdfwriter/PDFDocument.java#L76

PDF to be generated is very very huge.

Comment: Are you using buffer? Maybe post the code so it will be easier to understand

Comment: @nupadhyaya I am using StringBuilder.